# How to remove 9patch margins

Tags: java, android

this is my 9patch image :

[image]

as you can see, it has big corners at top left and bottom right .I made a 9patch image from it to stretch the image , it works fine but there is a problem , it gives the corners a big margin , look at this image :

[image]

I only can use the white box , the other space is just margins .

this is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/colorbg"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/roundads"
android:padding="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

as you can see, I've set padding to 0 but it takes the margins because of this 9patch .

Is there any way to remove this margins ?

Thanks

Comment: set the horizontal-padding and vertical-padding to the 9patch

Comment: What is that little bit of red on the right? Is this really the entire activity we are looking at in that screen shot?

Comment: @weston it's an screen shot

Comment: @AngadTiwari sorry I didn't get you , Could you explain it more ?

Comment: edit your patch image..and add vertical-padding and horizontal-padding..which is on the right side and bottom

Answer (score 1):

add vertical-padding and horizontal-padding something equivalent to this...and try

[image]